# Counting Documents in Mongo Cursor with C & BSON.

Tags: c, mongodb, bson

I'm working on a project and need to count the amount of documents (MongoDB) in a cursor with BSON and C.

Here is my code:

```
        bson_buffer_init(query_buf);
        bson_append_string(query_buf, "url", bson_iterator_string(it)); 
        bson_from_buffer(query, query_buf);
        similar = mongo_find(conn, "testing.test", query, NULL, 0, 0, 0);
        while(mongo_cursor_next(similar))
        {
            bson_iterator it2[1]; 
            if(bson_find(it2, &similar->current, "url"))
            {
                printf("%s\n", bson_iterator_string(it2));
            }

        }
```

How would I alter this in order to count the documents in each cursor (the above is in a loop, url is different each pass)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `mongo_count` method?

According to the source, it's right about here:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/master/src/mongo.c#L385

Note that the C drivers are still considered Alpha quality. If you find any bugs, please let the MongoDB team know: http://jira.mongodb.org/